# How to repeater field data save as pivot table instead of the JSON format?

Tags: pivot, backend, repeater, octobercms

Could you please help me with the below requirement?

What I have done?

> I have created the repeater field for adding the dynamic data and save it in the database as the same column with JSON format. But now I want to move these data to the pivot table.

> So Guys do you know how can I do these functionalities in Octobercms in the backend area.

> Please Help me or give me an idea of how can I do that.

Guys thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give more details on what the pivot data is for. You are best to use the native relations manager in the controller. [Check Here](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations#relation-display)

Comment: @PettisBrandon I want to add the repeater field data in the pivot table, generally, repeater field data has added as JSON type in the main model table.